# Show equivalence between the expression $\min_{X \subseteq S}$ and $\min_{I \subseteq \{1,...,n\}}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set and ${\cal A} = (A_1,...,A_n)$ a family of subsets of $S$. I wish to show that

$$\min_{X \subseteq S} \{|S-X| + |\{i: A_i \cap X \neq \emptyset\}|\} = \min_{I \subseteq \{1,..,n\}} \left\{\left|\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right| + n - |I|\right\}.$$

I am tryng to see if for each $X \subseteq S$, $S-X = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ with $I = \{i: A_i \cap X = \emptyset\}$. But for this case in that
$S = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $X = \{1,4\}$ and ${\cal A} = (A_1,A_2)$ with $A_1 = \{1\}$ and $A_2 = \{2\}$ is a counterexample. ${\cal A}$ is a family of subsets of $S$ in this case? How i can show this? if the way i'm doing is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The statement that for $X \subseteq S$, $S-X = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ with $I = \{i: A_i \cap X = \emptyset\}$ is only true of $A_i$ are disjoint and their union covers $S$. However, the equation is still true without those assumptions.

Let $X^* \subseteq S$ be the minimizer. Consider the set $\{i : A_i \cap X \neq \emptyset\} =: J$. Using this let us define $I = \{1, \ldots, n\} - J$. Then we have that $n - |I| = |J|$.

For $i \in I$, we have that $A_i \cap X = \emptyset$. Thus, $A_i \subset S - X$. Thus, we have that

$$ \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \subset S - X.$$

Thus, we have that

$$\min_{X \subseteq S} \{|S-X| + |\{i: A_i \cap X \neq \emptyset\}|\} \ge \min_{I \subseteq \{1,..,n\}} \left\{\left|\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right| + n - |I|\right\}.$$

How about the other direction. Let $I^*$ be the minimizer of the right hand side. Let $J = \{1,\ldots,n\} - I^*$. I now claim that for each $j \in J$ the sets $A_j - \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i \neq \emptyset$. Suppose for $j$ this was empty. Then if create $I = I^* \cup \{j\}$,then we have found an $I$ for which the right hand side has a smaller value than with $I^*$. This is a contradiction. Hence such a $j$ doesn't exists.

Let $x_j \in A_j - \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i$ be any such element. Let $X = \{x_j : j \in J\} \cup (S - \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i)$. Then we see that $\{i : A_i\cap X \neq \emptyset\} = J$ and for all $x \in S - X$, we have that $x \notin X$. Thus, $x \notin (S - \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i)$. But since $x \in S$, this implies that $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i$.

Thus, we have that $S-X \subset \bigcup_{i \in I}A_i$. Thus, we get the reverse inequality.